# Is there a way using flexbox to make images look like this?

Tags: css, flexbox

[How to display images like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMq4F.png)

I tried using using flex basis on two biggest images but rest of the images does not fit in the second row. I used properties on container :

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Ya you can by using a grid system

Comment: Do you want to stick with Flexbox when Grid sounds tempting?

Comment: I  can't do it with either one unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `flex` as code below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.container div {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.sub-wrap {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: blue;
}
.sub-wrap div {
  height: 50%;
}
.w-25 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background: red;
}
.w-small {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}
.w-double {
  flex: 0 0 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="w-25">1</div>

  <div class="sub-wrap">
    <div class="w-small">2</div>
    <div class="w-double">3</div>
    <div class="w-small">4</div>
    <div class="w-small">5</div>
    <div class="w-small">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-25">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 4):

I know you said flexbox but in this case I would give `grid-template-areas` a try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: a; }
.item2 { grid-area: b; }
.item3 { grid-area: c; }
.item4 { grid-area: d; }
.item5 { grid-area: e; }
.item6 { grid-area: f; }
.item7 { grid-area: g; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
            "a b c c d"
            "a e f g d";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">A</div>
  <div class="item2">B</div>
  <div class="item3">C</div>  
  <div class="item4">D</div>
  <div class="item5">E</div>
  <div class="item6">F</div>
  <div class="item7">G</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```